# Angular formly: is there a way to set default options for all inputs

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I'm having a formly form with many `mat-inputs` (yes, I'm using Material) inside. I want each of them have `appearance=outline` of cause I can put it inside `templateOptions` of each input. But that's not DRY. Is there a way to set default `appearance` for each `mat-input` in my app and do not put it in each input description?

**UPD.** I'm using formly form component in the following way

```
<formly-form [form]="form" [fields]="fieldsDescription"></formly-form>
```

`form` is generated with cycle (looping over `fieldsDescription` array) and angular form builder. `fieldsDescription` is downloaded from backend. Right now I put `appearance=outline` in each input. So `fieldsDescription` is an array of objects like the following

```
{
    "key": "field_key",
    "type": "input",
    "templateOptions": {
        "label": "A label",
        "appearance": "outline",
        "placeholder": "",
        "required": true
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want, you can use a provider MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, see the docs:https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use as provider MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS { appearance: 'outline' }? I imagine you want all yours inputs apparence outline. In your module

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'outline' } },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

why not using inside template `<mat-form-field appearance="outline">` ? assuming you use an `ngFor` there.

le:

```
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'Input',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Input',
        placeholder: 'Placeholder',
        description: 'Description',
        required: true,
        appearance: 'outline',
      },
    },
  ];
```

for Formly, you can use `templateOptions` to define appearance outline in your form fields configuration. source [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyxzi9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That's not my case. The code of form looks like the following `<formly-form [form]="form" [fields]="fieldsDescription"></formly-form>`. Form is generate with cycle and form builder, fieldsDescription too. But I don't deal with `mat-form-field`, it's done on formly side

Comment: I found something which can works for Formly. Answer updated

Comment: Yes, and that's the way I'm doing it right now. My question is about how can I avoid writing `appearance: 'outline'` every time. That's not DRY. Can't find any sort of default setting for components in formly

Comment: then, I think you need to provide some more code. How your formDescriptions is composed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change `defaultOptions` globally at once, you could try:

```
import { FormlyConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

constructor(private formlyConfig: FormlyConfig) {
  this.formlyConfig.setDefaultOptions({
    templateOptions: {
      appearance: 'outline',
    },
  });
}
```